# Android keyDispatchingTimedOut problem

Tags: android

In my android application i am implementing map functionality. it has a tab bar when i jump one activity to another activity through tab its working perfectly. but when i come on map activity and try to move from it through "Back key of device" the entire application freezes and after a couple of seconds I get the dreaded force close dialog appearing and i got error.

```
11-11 10:53:26.083: ERROR/ActivityManager(85): ANR in com.project.activity 
(com.project.activity/.MapActivity)
11-11 10:53:26.083: ERROR/ActivityManager(85): Reason: keyDispatchingTimedOut
11-11 10:53:26.083: ERROR/ActivityManager(85): Load: 2.64 / 1.75 / 1.64
11-11 10:53:26.083: ERROR/ActivityManager(85): CPU usage from 8749ms to 209ms ago:
11-11 10:53:26.083: ERROR/ActivityManager(85):   dianic.activity: 18% = 16% user + 1%  kernel / faults: 1938 minor
11-11 10:53:26.083: ERROR/ActivityManager(85):   mediaserver: 14% = 14% user + 0% kernel
11-11 10:53:26.083: ERROR/ActivityManager(85):   system_server: 4% = 2% user + 1% kernel / faults: 167 minor
11-11 10:53:26.083: ERROR/ActivityManager(85):   dhd_dpc: 1% = 0% user + 1% kernel
11-11 10:53:26.083: ERROR/ActivityManager(85):   android.vending: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 57 minor
11-11 10:53:26.083: ERROR/ActivityManager(85):   synaptics_wq: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
11-11 10:53:26.083: ERROR/ActivityManager(85):   e.process.gapps: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 3 minor
11-11 10:53:26.083: ERROR/ActivityManager(85):   wpa_supplicant: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
11-11 10:53:26.083: ERROR/ActivityManager(85):   logcat: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
11-11 10:53:26.083: ERROR/ActivityManager(85): TOTAL: 41% = 36% user + 5% kernel + 0% softirq
```

please guide me why this is occurring.. thanks in advance

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467205/android-key-dispatching-timed-out/27292747#27292747

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This type of problem occur when code get window leak type of problem or when we try to perform many operation on same activity...

Comment: this question has been answered using thread(). refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467205/android-key-dispatching-timed-out