# keyDispatchingTimedOut while using emulator

Tags: java, android, performance, android-emulator

While using honeycomb emulator is shows following error and become very slow.

```
02-11 02:58:50.949: ERROR/ActivityManager(365): ANR in com.android.launcher (com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher)
02-11 02:58:50.949: ERROR/ActivityManager(365): Reason: keyDispatchingTimedOut
02-11 02:58:50.949: ERROR/ActivityManager(365): Load: 2.57 / 1.18 / 0.89
02-11 02:58:50.949: ERROR/ActivityManager(365): CPU usage from 3042ms to -7585ms ago:
02-11 02:58:50.949: ERROR/ActivityManager(365):   74% 365/system_server: 53% user + 21% kernel / faults: 335 minor
02-11 02:58:50.949: ERROR/ActivityManager(365):   9% 780/zygote: 3.8% user + 5.1% kernel / faults: 915 minor
02-11 02:58:50.949: ERROR/ActivityManager(365):   8.2% 684/com.android.launcher: 6% user + 2.1% kernel / faults: 51 minor
02-11 02:58:50.949: ERROR/ActivityManager(365):   0% 432/zygote: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 22 minor
02-11 02:58:50.949: ERROR/ActivityManager(365):   2.4% 41/adbd: 0.3% user + 2% kernel
02-11 02:58:50.949: ERROR/ActivityManager(365):   0.4% 546/com.android.systemui: 0.1% user + 0.2% kernel / faults: 11 minor
02-11 02:58:50.949: ERROR/ActivityManager(365):   0.5% 733/logcat: 0% user + 0.5% kernel
02-11 02:58:50.949: ERROR/ActivityManager(365):   0% 425/zygote: 0% user + 0% kernel
02-11 02:58:50.949: ERROR/ActivityManager(365):   0% 28/servicemanager: 0% user + 0% kernel
02-11 02:58:50.949: ERROR/ActivityManager(365): 100% TOTAL: 65% user + 34% kernel + 0.6% softirq
02-11 02:58:50.949: ERROR/ActivityManager(365): CPU usage from 9680ms to 11220ms later:
02-11 02:58:50.949: ERROR/ActivityManager(365):   70% 365/system_server: 28% user + 42% kernel
02-11 02:58:50.949: ERROR/ActivityManager(365):     49% 396/InputDispatcher: 18% user + 30% kernel
02-11 02:58:50.949: ERROR/ActivityManager(365):     21% 366/HeapWorker: 8.1% user + 13% kernel
02-11 02:58:50.949: ERROR/ActivityManager(365):   26% 78014% user + 11% kernel / faults: 323 minor
02-11 02:58:50.949: ERROR/ActivityManager(365):     20% 780/.ap: 10% user + 10% kernel
02-11 02:58:50.949: ERROR/ActivityManager(365):     5.4% 781/HeapWorker: 4.6% user + 0.7% kernel
02-11 02:58:50.949: ERROR/ActivityManager(365):   1.3% 41/adbd: 0% user + 1.3% kernel
02-11 02:58:50.949: ERROR/ActivityManager(365):     0.6% 41/adbd: 0% user + 0.6% kernel
02-11 02:58:50.949: ERROR/ActivityManager(365):     0.6% 65/adbd: 0% user + 0.6% kernel
02-11 02:58:50.949: ERROR/ActivityManager(365):   0.7% 684/com.android.launcher: 0.7% user + 0% kernel
02-11 02:58:50.949: ERROR/ActivityManager(365):     0.7% 684/ndroid.launcher: 0.7% user + 0% kernel
02-11 02:58:50.949: ERROR/ActivityManager(365):     0.7% 691/Binder Thread #: 0.7% user + 0% kernel
02-11 02:58:50.949: ERROR/ActivityManager(365): 100% TOTAL: 40% user + 58% kernel + 0.6% softirq
```

What did went wrong here. What i need fix this?
thank you

Comment: I am also facing the same issue... did you find any solution

Answer (score 2):

This is actually `ANR (Activity not responding)`

your activity is taking long enough to execute the task you provided

Below links have info regarding how to force it to be responsive thru `THREADS`.

You should execute *heavy log running tasks* in seperate `THREAD` or `Async Task`

[Simlar Problen in SO with solution Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4611060/1206052)

and

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5513623/1206052)

Answer (score 1):

- 1) You might have used thread.sleep()
  in your UI thread. That is not cool
  and android just kicks your activity.
- 2) You are doing some massive bad ass computation in your UI thread. Use an [AsyncTask](http://www.screaming-penguin.com/node/7746) or a Thread.
- 3) The emulator is sometimes slower than a phone.

Answer (score 1):

This error is because of your avd took long time to run your [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html).

http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html

If you did any complex task in your UI thread your application will become very slow. to solve this problem you can use [painless thread](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2009/05/painless-threading.html),[painless thread](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/05/painless-threading.html).

taken from [Blundell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5513457/anr-keydispatchingtimedout-error/5513623#5513623)`s answer.

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Seems as if you are doing some complex computation at the time when activity is loading.

`ANR(Activity Not Responding)`

Generally ANR is trigger if `Activity` fails to tell the android OS that "I am still alive".
[android Developer](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html).

You need to execute in  Async manner.
So for an instance if you want to do some long waiting process `onClick()`.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
  new DownloadImageTask().execute("http://example.com/image.png");// Any time Taking Event.
}

private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask {
     protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
         return loadImageFromNetwork(urls[0]);
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
         mImageView.setImageBitmap(result);
     }
 }
```