# ANR keyDispatchingTimedOut error

Tags: android, android-anr-dialog

i m getting this force down error in my app,when i m trying to parse RSS with DOM.it's not always the force down problem however...this is the logcat:

```
**ANR keyDispatchingTimedOut**

DALVIK THREADS:
"main" prio=5 tid=1 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x40025b50 self=0xcdb8
  | sysTid=2504 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=bg_non_interactive handle=-1345017804
  | schedstat=( 573577878 521301271 1476 )
  at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.readSocketImpl(Native Method)
  at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.read(OSNetworkSystem.java:358)
  at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:561)
  at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:88)
  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl$ChunkedInputStream.read(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:458)
  at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:275)
  at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.peek(KXmlParser.java:931)
  at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.pushText(KXmlParser.java:881)
  at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.nextImpl(KXmlParser.java:354)
  at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.nextToken(KXmlParser.java:1406)
  at org.apache.harmony.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:369)
  at org.apache.harmony.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:362)
  at org.apache.harmony.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:362)
  at org.apache.harmony.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:362)
  at org.apache.harmony.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:362)
  at org.apache.harmony.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:135)
  at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:110)
  at kostas.menu.olympiakos.DomFeedParser.parse(DomFeedParser.java:26)
  at kostas.menu.olympiakos.nea.loadFeed(nea.java:51)
  at kostas.menu.olympiakos.nea.onCreate(nea.java:38)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1066)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2799)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2866)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:140)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2181)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5097)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

"Binder Thread #2" prio=5 tid=6 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x46eea810 self=0x135a00
  | sysTid=2509 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=bg_non_interactive handle=1213600
  | schedstat=( 10253904 21514895 127 )
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Binder Thread #1" prio=5 tid=5 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x46eea748 self=0x12cab0
  | sysTid=2508 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=bg_non_interactive handle=1301736
  | schedstat=( 12603756 119659428 129 )
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Compiler" daemon prio=5 tid=4 VMWAIT
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x46ee32a8 self=0x127bc8
  | sysTid=2507 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=bg_non_interactive handle=1300256
  | schedstat=( 197021496 268585180 1155 )
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Signal Catcher" daemon prio=5 tid=3 RUNNABLE
  | group="system" sCount=0 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x46ee31e8 self=0xa8140
  | sysTid=2506 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=bg_non_interactive handle=1299816
  | schedstat=( 915528 5706786 7 )
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"HeapWorker" daemon prio=5 tid=2 VMWAIT
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x45947800 self=0x1224b8
  | sysTid=2505 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=bg_non_interactive handle=1212984
  | schedstat=( 27404784 3082276 24 )
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

Comment: this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/704311/android-how-do-i-investigate-an-anr

Answer (score 47, accepted):

ANR Error

Activity Not Responding.

Your activity took to long to say to the Android OS 'hey i'm still alive'! (This is what the UI thread does).

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/responsiveness.html

Basically if you make the UI thread do some complex task it's too busy doing your task to tell the OS that it is still 'alive'.

http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2009/05/painless-threading.html

You should move your XML Parsing code to another thread, then use a callback to tell the UI thread you have finished and to do something with the result.

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html

Answer (score 14):

If Logcat doesn't output anything usefull, try to pull traces.txt from /data/anr/traces.txt

> adb pull /data/anr/traces.txt .

as it may give more information on where the ANR Exception occurrred

Comment: Thanks a bunch, this gave me a nice stacktrace of where the faults were.

Answer (score 2):

Don't run blocking operations on the UI thread. Launch your own thread or use the [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) class for a more convenient way to solve this.