# Issue with thread handler in Android

Tags: android, handler

In my app I am trying to parse some values from url whenever the user hits any button. In the same way I am using handler thread to refresh my app automatically for every one hour.

But at the time of refreshment the parsing process gets started and at the time if the user hits any button the app gets crashed automatically. In the logcat it shows the error to be as

```
Android ANR keyDispatchingTimedOut Error
```

How can I continue the operations in my app without any crash. Is it possible to stop the parsing in between....

Please, help me friends...

Comment: What do you mean by handler thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check below link more helpful to you

[ANR keyDispatchingTimedOut error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5513457/anr-keydispatchingtimedout-error)