# How can I get html text from a website url in android?

Tags: android

```
public class TestProjMain extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final EditText eText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.address);
        final TextView tView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pagetext);


        final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonGo);
        button.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    tView.setText("");
                // Perform action on click
                    URL url = new URL(/*"http://www.google.com"*/eText.getText().toString());
                    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
                    // Get the response
                    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                    String line = "";
                    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {


                        tView.append(line);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        });        
    }
}
```

I wrote this but its not working. I also used the httpclient code but that was also not working. My emulator stops responding every time whenever I execute this function. I don't know where the problem is?? somebody please help !! thanks in advance...

Comment: You can't do this on the UI thread. Create a new thread or service, go get the code and parse it, then use a handler to tell your UI thread your finished and to do something.

Comment: He can better use AsynTask class

Comment: This is why it is not responding: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5513457/anr-keydispatchingtimedout-error/5513623#5513623

Comment: Did u add internet permission in manifest ?

Answer (score 3):

Its better to use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to make a web call.

Use the methods of AsyncTask as follows:

1. In doInBackground() method, write your below code:

   ```
   URL url = new URL(/*"http://www.google.com"*/eText.getText().toString());
   URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
   // Get the response
   BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
   String line = "";
   ```
2. In onPostExecute() method, write your display code:

   ```
           while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {


               tView.append(line);
           }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Use an asynctask like so

```
public class RetrieveSiteData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(16384);

    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(urls[0]);

    try {
        HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpGet);
        InputStream content = execute.getEntity().getContent();

        BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
        String s = "";
        while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(s);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return builder.toString();
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

}
```

}