# WIN DEATH error in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity

Sometimes, my application is frozen and after that it is crashed.

I read the system logs and I saw some error on my Activity as "WIN DEATH" at last lines of the system logs.

Someone can tell me the reason and show me the solve?

Thank you so much!

Here is system logs:

```
08-17 08:34:00.091 E/WifiService(  149): ***WAPI : readNetworkVariables testing for WAPI
08-17 08:34:00.101 E/WifiService(  149): ***WAPI : readNetworkVariables testing for WAPI
08-17 08:34:00.101 E/WifiService(  149): ***WAPI : readNetworkVariables testing for WAPI
08-17 08:34:00.111 E/WifiService(  149): ***WAPI : readNetworkVariables testing for WAPI
08-17 08:34:00.121 E/WifiService(  149): ***WAPI : readNetworkVariables testing for WAPI
08-17 08:34:00.131 E/WifiService(  149): ***WAPI : readNetworkVariables testing for WAPI
08-17 08:34:00.131 E/WifiService(  149): ***WAPI : readNetworkVariables testing for WAPI
08-17 08:34:00.141 E/WifiService(  149): ***WAPI : readNetworkVariables testing for WAPI
08-17 08:34:00.151 E/WifiService(  149): ***WAPI : readNetworkVariables testing for WAPI
08-17 08:34:00.151 E/WifiService(  149): ***WAPI : readNetworkVariables testing for WAPI
08-17 08:34:00.161 E/WifiService(  149): ***WAPI : readNetworkVariables testing for WAPI
08-17 08:34:00.171 E/WifiService(  149): ***WAPI : readNetworkVariables testing for WAPI
08-17 08:34:00.171 E/WifiService(  149): ***WAPI : readNetworkVariables testing for WAPI
08-17 08:34:00.181 E/WifiService(  149): ***WAPI : readNetworkVariables testing for WAPI
08-17 08:34:00.191 E/WifiService(  149): ***WAPI : readNetworkVariables testing for WAPI
08-17 08:34:00.191 E/WifiService(  149): ***WAPI : readNetworkVariables testing for WAPI
08-17 08:34:00.211 E/WifiService(  149): ***WAPI : readNetworkVariables testing for WAPI
08-17 08:34:01.692 I/ActivityManager(  149): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.HOME] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.dell.launcher/.Launcher }
08-17 08:34:01.711 D/StatusBar(  149): nAnimY < mStatusBarView.getHeight()
08-17 08:34:01.731 W/InputManagerService(  149): Ignoring hideSoftInput of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@46f51200
08-17 08:34:01.751 I/ActivityManager(  149): No longer want com.android.vending (pid 724): hidden #16
08-17 08:34:03.141 I/ActivityManager(  149): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.android.browser/.BrowserActivity bnds=[289,313][375,390] }
08-17 08:34:03.521 W/InputManagerService(  149): Starting input on non-focused client com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@46ee34f8 (uid=10006 pid=893)
08-17 08:34:03.521 W/InputManagerService(  149): Client not active, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@46f02ef0
08-17 08:34:08.301 I/ActivityManager(  149): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=http://vnexpress.net/ flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.android.browser/.BrowserActivity (has extras) }
08-17 08:34:43.361 I/ActivityManager(  149): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW cat=[android.intent.category.BROWSABLE] dat=http://vnexpress.net/gl/the-gioi/phan-tich/2012/08/trung-quoc-se-bi-co-lap-neu-bat-hop-tac-ve-bien-dong-1/ cmp=com.android.browser/.BrowserActivity }
08-17 08:34:43.911 I/ActivityManager(  149): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW cat=[android.intent.category.BROWSABLE] dat=http://vnexpress.net/gl/the-gioi/phan-tich/2012/08/trung-quoc-se-bi-co-lap-neu-bat-hop-tac-ve-bien-dong-1/ cmp=com.android.browser/.BrowserActivity }
08-17 08:35:06.701 I/ActivityManager(  149): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.HOME] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.dell.launcher/.Launcher }
08-17 08:35:06.711 D/StatusBar(  149): nAnimY < mStatusBarView.getHeight()
08-17 08:35:06.751 W/InputManagerService(  149): Ignoring hideSoftInput of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@47017a48
08-17 08:35:10.341 I/ActivityManager(  149): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=i3.mobile1/i3.mobile.dvrremote.screen.WelcomeScreen }
08-17 08:35:10.361 D/StatusBar(  149): nAnimY < mStatusBarView.getHeight()
08-17 08:35:16.144 W/WindowManager(  149): Key dispatching timed out sending to i3.mobile1/i3.mobile.dvrremote.screen.ConnectScreen
08-17 08:35:16.144 W/WindowManager(  149): Previous dispatch state: null
08-17 08:35:16.144 W/WindowManager(  149): Current dispatch state: {{null to Window{47004958 i3.mobile1/i3.mobile.dvrremote.screen.ConnectScreen paused=false} @ 1345167316145 lw=Window{47004958 i3.mobile1/i3.mobile.dvrremote.screen.ConnectScreen paused=false} lb=android.os.BinderProxy@46e87e58 fin=false gfw=true ed=true tts=0 wf=false fp=false mcf=Window{47004958 i3.mobile1/i3.mobile.dvrremote.screen.ConnectScreen paused=false}}}
08-17 08:35:16.421 E/ActivityManager(  149): ANR in i3.mobile1i3.mobile1(pid: 941) (i3.mobile1/i3.mobile.dvrremote.screen.ConnectScreen)
08-17 08:35:16.421 E/ActivityManager(  149): Reason: keyDispatchingTimedOut
08-17 08:35:16.421 E/ActivityManager(  149): Load: 5.13 / 5.05 / 3.69
08-17 08:35:16.421 E/ActivityManager(  149): CPU usage from 5531ms to 13ms ago:
08-17 08:35:16.421 E/ActivityManager(  149):   system_server: 2% = 1% user + 1% kernel / faults: 35 minor 19 major
08-17 08:35:16.421 E/ActivityManager(  149):   android.browser: 1% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 21 minor 2 major
08-17 08:35:16.421 E/ActivityManager(  149):   m.android.phone: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 48 minor 2 major
08-17 08:35:16.421 E/ActivityManager(  149):   e.process.gapps: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 21 minor 1 major
08-17 08:35:16.421 E/ActivityManager(  149):   m.dell.launcher: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 20 minor
08-17 08:35:16.421 E/ActivityManager(  149):   events/0: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
08-17 08:35:16.421 E/ActivityManager(  149):   auo_touchscreen: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
08-17 08:35:16.421 E/ActivityManager(  149):   d.process.acore: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 23 minor
08-17 08:35:16.421 E/ActivityManager(  149):   m.android.music: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 219 minor 1 major
08-17 08:35:16.421 E/ActivityManager(  149):   com.oem.lota: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 53 minor 1 major
08-17 08:35:16.421 E/ActivityManager(  149):   ndroid.dellsync: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 43 minor
08-17 08:35:16.421 E/ActivityManager(  149):   cpanda.aquapets: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 61 minor
08-17 08:35:16.421 E/ActivityManager(  149):   ndroid.settings: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 14 minor
08-17 08:35:16.421 E/ActivityManager(  149):   lite.dellstreak: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 25 minor
08-17 08:35:16.421 E/ActivityManager(  149):   d.photos:Remote: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 17 minor
08-17 08:35:16.421 E/ActivityManager(  149):   equicksearchbox: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 22 minor
08-17 08:35:16.421 E/ActivityManager(  149): TOTAL: 7% = 3% user + 3% kernel + 0% iowait
08-17 08:35:16.551 W/WindowManager(  149): No window to dispatch pointer action 1
08-17 08:35:16.591 W/WindowManager(  149): No window to dispatch pointer action 1
08-17 08:35:16.591 W/WindowManager(  149): No window to dispatch pointer action 0
08-17 08:35:16.591 W/WindowManager(  149): No window to dispatch pointer action 1
08-17 08:35:16.591 W/WindowManager(  149): No window to dispatch pointer action 0
08-17 08:35:16.591 W/WindowManager(  149): No window to dispatch pointer action 1
08-17 08:35:16.591 W/WindowManager(  149): No window to dispatch pointer action 0
08-17 08:35:16.591 W/WindowManager(  149): No window to dispatch pointer action 1
08-17 08:35:16.591 W/WindowManager(  149): No window to dispatch pointer action 0
08-17 08:35:16.881 W/WindowManager(  149): No window to dispatch pointer action 1
08-17 08:35:20.351 W/ActivityManager(  149): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
08-17 08:35:20.361 W/ActivityManager(  149): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{46e20d08 i3.mobile1/i3.mobile.dvrremote.screen.ConnectScreen}
08-17 08:35:48.398 W/WindowManager(  149): Key dispatching timed out sending to i3.mobile1/i3.mobile.dvrremote.screen.ConnectScreen
08-17 08:35:48.398 W/WindowManager(  149): Previous dispatch state: null
08-17 08:35:48.398 W/WindowManager(  149): Current dispatch state: {{null to Window{47004958 i3.mobile1/i3.mobile.dvrremote.screen.ConnectScreen paused=false} @ 1345167348400 lw=Window{47004958 i3.mobile1/i3.mobile.dvrremote.screen.ConnectScreen paused=false} lb=android.os.BinderProxy@46e87e58 fin=false gfw=true ed=true tts=0 wf=false fp=false mcf=Window{47004958 i3.mobile1/i3.mobile.dvrremote.screen.ConnectScreen paused=false}}}
08-17 08:35:48.841 E/ActivityManager(  149): ANR in i3.mobile1i3.mobile1(pid: 941) (i3.mobile1/i3.mobile.dvrremote.screen.ConnectScreen)
08-17 08:35:48.841 E/ActivityManager(  149): Reason: keyDispatchingTimedOut
08-17 08:35:48.841 E/ActivityManager(  149): Load: 5.28 / 5.11 / 3.76
08-17 08:35:48.841 E/ActivityManager(  149): CPU usage from 32415ms to 58ms ago:
08-17 08:35:48.841 E/ActivityManager(  149):   system_server: 6% = 4% user + 1% kernel / faults: 840 minor 1 major
08-17 08:35:48.841 E/ActivityManager(  149):   android.browser: 1% = 1% user + 0% kernel / faults: 109 minor
08-17 08:35:48.841 E/ActivityManager(  149):   .oem.logservice: 1% = 1% user + 0% kernel / faults: 1378 minor
08-17 08:35:48.841 E/ActivityManager(  149):   m.dell.launcher: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 74 minor
08-17 08:35:48.841 E/ActivityManager(  149):   ndroid.settings: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 72 minor
08-17 08:35:48.841 E/ActivityManager(  149):   mmcqd: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
08-17 08:35:48.841 E/ActivityManager(  149):   sensors_daemon: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
08-17 08:35:48.841 E/ActivityManager(  149):   e.process.gapps: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 34 minor
08-17 08:35:48.841 E/ActivityManager(  149):   mmcqd: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
08-17 08:35:48.841 E/ActivityManager(  149):   cpanda.aquapets: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 7 minor
08-17 08:35:48.841 E/ActivityManager(  149):   kswapd0: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
08-17 08:35:48.841 E/ActivityManager(  149):   d.process.acore: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 42 minor
08-17 08:35:48.841 E/ActivityManager(  149):   events/0: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
08-17 08:35:48.841 E/ActivityManager(  149):   kjournald: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
08-17 08:35:48.841 E/ActivityManager(  149):   ksdioirqd/mmc1: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
08-17 08:35:48.841 E/ActivityManager(  149):   oid.inputmethod: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 25 minor 1 major
08-17 08:35:48.841 E/ActivityManager(  149):   m.android.phone: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 1 minor
08-17 08:35:48.841 E/ActivityManager(  149):   equicksearchbox: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 1 minor
08-17 08:35:48.841 E/ActivityManager(  149):   auo_touchscreen: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
08-17 08:35:48.841 E/ActivityManager(  149):   wpa_supplicant: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
08-17 08:35:48.841 E/ActivityManager(  149):   viders.calendar: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 35 minor
08-17 08:35:48.841 E/ActivityManager(  149):   d.process.media: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 18 minor
08-17 08:35:48.841 E/ActivityManager(  149):   m.android.music: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 1 minor
08-17 08:35:48.841 E/ActivityManager(  149):   ndroid.dellsync: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 1 minor
08-17 08:35:48.841 E/ActivityManager(  149):   .packagechecker: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 20 minor
08-17 08:35:48.841 E/ActivityManager(  149):   com.netgate: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 273 minor
08-17 08:35:48.841 E/ActivityManager(  149):   .cooliris.media: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 25 minor
08-17 08:35:48.841 E/ActivityManager(  149):   lite.dellstreak: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 1 minor
08-17 08:35:48.841 E/ActivityManager(  149):   ogle.android.gm: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 30 minor 1 major
08-17 08:35:48.841 E/ActivityManager(  149):   d.apps.uploader: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 17 minor
08-17 08:35:48.841 E/ActivityManager(  149):   d.photos:Remote: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 1 minor
08-17 08:35:48.841 E/ActivityManager(  149):   o.android.oemec: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 15 minor
08-17 08:35:48.841 E/ActivityManager(  149):   i3.mobile1: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 16 minor 1 major
08-17 08:35:48.841 E/ActivityManager(  149): TOTAL: 32% = 11% user + 8% kernel + 12% iowait + 0% irq + 0% softirq
08-17 08:35:48.871 W/WindowManager(  149): No window to dispatch pointer action 1
08-17 08:35:48.901 W/WindowManager(  149): No window to dispatch pointer action 1
08-17 08:35:48.901 W/WindowManager(  149): No window to dispatch pointer action 0
08-17 08:35:48.901 W/WindowManager(  149): No window to dispatch pointer action 1
08-17 08:35:48.901 W/WindowManager(  149): No window to dispatch pointer action 0
08-17 08:35:48.901 W/WindowManager(  149): No window to dispatch pointer action 1
08-17 08:35:48.901 W/WindowManager(  149): No window to dispatch pointer action 0
08-17 08:35:49.392 W/WindowManager(  149): No window to dispatch pointer action 1
08-17 08:35:51.681 W/ActivityManager(  149):   Force finishing activity i3.mobile1/i3.mobile.dvrremote.screen.ConnectScreen
08-17 08:35:51.681 I/ActivityManager(  149): Killing i3.mobile1 (pid=941): user's request
08-17 08:35:51.701 I/WindowManager(  149): WIN DEATH: Window{46e6fdb0 i3.mobile1/i3.mobile.dvrremote.screen.WelcomeScreen paused=false}
08-17 08:35:51.711 I/ActivityManager(  149): Process i3.mobile1 (pid 941) has died.
08-17 08:35:51.721 I/WindowManager(  149): WIN DEATH: Window{47004958 i3.mobile1/i3.mobile.dvrremote.screen.ConnectScreen paused=true}
08-17 08:35:51.721 I/ActivityManager(  149): Start proc i3.mobile1 for activity i3.mobile1/i3.mobile.dvrremote.screen.WelcomeScreen: pid=1119 uid=10106 gids={1015, 3003}
```

Thank you!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/5513623/1321873

Comment: Thank you, I have detected the problem.

Comment: It's not really an error.  It's just an informational line.  Notice the **I** in **I/WindowManager**

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your app is probably killed due to the ANR (Application Not Responding). That may happen when you do some hard processing in the UI thread. You can read more here: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/responsiveness.html

There is only one solution: move all the hard work into the background thread so the UI thread will stay responsive.

Comment: Yes, the log contains this line:
08-17 08:35:48.841 E/ActivityManager(  149): ANR in i3.mobile1i3.mobile1(pid: 941) (i3.mobile1/i3.mobile.dvrremote.screen.ConnectScreen)

Comment: Thanks all, the problem is in ConnectScreen and I have fixed it.