# Android sometimes force kills application

Tags: android

I start activity A, then start activity B.
I press home button, then waiting long time.
When I resume application, it force stopped.

```
02-03 18:42:54.413 828-844/system_process I/ActivityManager: Force stopping ru.tabor.search appid=10089 user=0: from pid 20405
02-03 18:42:54.414 828-844/system_process I/ActivityManager: Killing 30212:ru.tabor.search/u0a89 (adj 7): stop ru.tabor.search
02-03 18:42:54.445 828-5948/system_process I/WindowState: WIN DEATH: Window{18b92c9b u0 ru.tabor.search/ru.tabor.search.modules.authorization.AuthorizationActivity}
02-03 18:42:54.447 828-845/system_process I/WindowState: WIN DEATH: Window{1cd0cfe4 u0 ru.tabor.search/ru.tabor.search.modules.registration.RegistrationActivity}
02-03 18:42:54.519 828-844/system_process I/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity 3 ActivityRecord{25a8977f u0 ru.tabor.search/.modules.authorization.AuthorizationActivity t2593}
02-03 18:42:54.520 828-844/system_process I/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity 3 ActivityRecord{d516838 u0 ru.tabor.search/.modules.registration.RegistrationActivity t2593}
02-03 18:42:54.523 828-20666/system_process W/ActivityManager: Spurious death for ProcessRecord{21ff313b 0:ru.tabor.search/u0a89}, curProc for 30212: null
02-03 18:42:59.890 828-1247/system_process I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10100000 cmp=ru.tabor.search/.modules.authorization.AuthorizationActivity} from uid 10089 on display 0
02-03 18:42:59.903 828-1247/system_process V/WindowManager: addAppToken: AppWindowToken{1c4987a0 token=Token{279a08a3 ActivityRecord{9f5afd2 u0 ru.tabor.search/.modules.authorization.AuthorizationActivity t2593}}} to stack=1 task=2593 at 0
02-03 18:42:59.919 828-891/system_process V/WindowManager: Adding window Window{1735e91b u0 Starting ru.tabor.search} at 4 of 8 (after Window{2ab6bf53 u0 com.cleanmaster.mguard/com.keniu.security.main.MainActivity})
02-03 18:43:19.288 828-1673/system_process I/ActivityManager: Start proc 21366:ru.tabor.search/u0a89 for activity ru.tabor.search/.modules.authorization.AuthorizationActivity
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Welcome to Android.  Perhaps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13009499/win-death-error-in-android

Comment: Do you have any Exception in the log?

Comment: I don't have any exceptions. It's very strange.

Comment: Can you share your code here?

Comment: If create hello world project with edittext, the bug appears after use freemem app (simulate low memory behaviour).

Comment: is clean master killing your background apps?

Comment: No. Clean master doesn't kill. But application doesn't restore state after free memory, with the log information.

Comment: So you use  an app that frees memory by clearing it and then when you go back to your app it dies because its data isnt in memory to restore state. If only I  could find a correlation

Comment: If wait a long time, then there is the same. I tested on any devices.

Comment: You need to share your code then someone can understand problem

Comment: May be your phone memory will be low and the os will be killing your app

Comment: please provide your phone specification?

Comment: are you using any native code? Segfault could lead to silent force close, at least that happened to my apps sometimes

Comment: provide activity B code

Answer (score 0):

As mush as i know , you cant do anything about that !!!
that is the behavior of android garbage collection system !

as i remember, the android do garbage collection by itself, if you do not use an activity for a long time in background, it will be garbage collected by the system to make ram free for other apps and processes.

if you have any information in that activity which you want to keep, save it here;

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState, PersistableBundle outPersistentState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState, outPersistentState);
}
```

when you back to that activity,

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if(savedInstanceState!=null){
    // GET #savedInstanceState AND USE THE OBJECT YOU STORED
    }
}
```

thats all you can do.

Comment: The onCreate method calls with null bundle.

Comment: i edited my answer. the first time you enter activity its null, so you must put a null check.

Answer (score 0):

Do you pass something as an Intent extra to the activity? 
If not, try removing clean master from your device.

Comment: The problem still exists when I removed clean master.

Comment: Do you pass something as an extra on the activity intent?

Comment: I don't pass something extras.

Comment: Do you have StrictMode enabled in your app?

Answer (score 0):

is your app leaking? if the phone is running low in memory, it will kill the memory hog app. if there is a process running on those activity, transfer it to a service and call startForeground() inside oncreate.

Comment: My activity kills itself (or ActivityManager kills Activity), and loses input data.

Comment: then do what Smartiz has answered above

Answer (score 0):

[Recreating an Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html) says:

> The system may also destroy your activity if it's currently stopped
>   and hasn't been used in a long time or the foreground activity
>   requires more resources so the system must shut down background
>   processes to recover memory.

So you can't stop system from killing your application.

To overcome it you should override [onRestoreInstanceState](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29) method. In this case you can save state of activity when system kills it and then restore when you navigating back to this activity.

Another option is implementing own [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html).

Quote from [Services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) API guide:

> The Android system will force-stop a service only when memory is low
>   and it must recover system resources for the activity that has user
>   focus.

Comment: It took me a long time to see that this was the cause of my fragments overlapping. When the app was recreated, activity X creates one fragment for default and restored another one...Just a mess. I had to check on activity X if savedInstanceState != null to open the right fragment. And change fragments to use findViewById just onCreateView. When I had his on onCreate, that situation generate a NullPointerException :|

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Android memory is limited so Virtual Machine can remove any piece of code that might be un-necessary.

Have a look into **Activity life-cycle** method, specially into `onResume` and make sure that you understand that perfectly. So many time application crashes just for improper use Activity life-cycle's methods.

Another important part is design consideration for Activity is, no matter what happened with persistence data your Activity should display its UI with some default value. So assumption is like this, *if I have data I will display if I don't, I really do not care*. **Your UI should never crash with or without data**. You can use **Resources**, say for example `String.xml`, `dimens.xml` for storing some default value or even in layouts.

If you still want go with singleton class, which is perfectly fine but make sure you do the following checking every time you try to access your singleton.

```
if (instance==null)
    instance=CurrentActivity.getInstance()
```

`getInstance()` method not only return you current instance it will also make sure that

- It initializes all object and variable
- Other singleton methods as instance method

Do not statically access data from one Activity to another. It is not good for android specially for the type problem you are facing now and also it is not very good OOP programming practice.

I recommended [SharedPreference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). Too much better way to persist data, if that meet your requirement go for it.

If you want to pass data from different Android component like Activity, Service or BroadcastReciever you can put it inside a bundle and and send as intent. And, as always their are SQLLite data storage, file IO etc etc.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you application is being killed by android OS because of memory overload or there can be a case some sort of process is running in your main thread you need to check it.. Also override OnResume function and check what results are you getting.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is very old, but for those people still looking for answer, Try turning Battery Optimisation and Doze Mode off for your particular app from Android Settings. This should work.