# Reason Why Android Process gets killed when Task Manager is showing

Tags: android, xamarin, process, kill

My Xamarin app gets  killed by Android when the Task Manager shows 3 or so apps (including my app)

I'm wondering how i can find out "Why" Android is killing my App ? and none of the other apps.

i found [WIN DEATH error in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13009499/win-death-error-in-android) and it could be because of an ANR, but then is there a way to find out ,what my application is so busy with on the main thread (without being able to use the Xamarin profiler..we only have VS professional , not VS enterprise)

Any help is appreciated.

thanks,
tom

The Device Log shows (reverse chronological order) : (the app is called toms_app_tablet)

```
04-06 12:32:30.241  Samsung SM-T365Y    Debug   27951   daemonapp   [MSC_Daemon]>>> AWDCDS:28 [0:0] AWD CD Act : androidintentactionPACKAGE_RESTARTED
04-06 12:32:30.241  Samsung SM-T365Y    Error   359 installd    system dir 1 : /system/priv-app/
04-06 12:32:30.241  Samsung SM-T365Y    Debug   997 PackageManager  remove MCS_UNBIND message and Posting MCS_UNBIND 10 secs later
04-06 12:32:30.241  Samsung SM-T365Y    Debug   1452    RegisteredServicesCache empty dynamic service
04-06 12:32:30.241  Samsung SM-T365Y    Error   359 installd    system dir 0 : /system/app/
04-06 12:32:30.231  Samsung SM-T365Y    Verbose 997 BroadcastQueue  [background] Process cur broadcast BroadcastRecord{dcc764e u0 android.intent.action.PACKAGE_RESTARTED qIdx=4} DELIVERED for app ProcessRecord{39e44a46 27951:com.sec.android.daemonapp/u0a75}
04-06 12:32:30.231  Samsung SM-T365Y    Verbose 997 BroadcastQueue  [background] Process cur broadcast BroadcastRecord{dcc764e u0 android.intent.action.PACKAGE_RESTARTED qIdx=4} DELIVERED for app ProcessRecord{faedae0 997:system/1000}
04-06 12:32:30.231  Samsung SM-T365Y    Error   359 installd    system dir 0 : /system/app/
04-06 12:32:30.231  Samsung SM-T365Y    Debug   997 PackageManager  remove MCS_UNBIND message and Posting MCS_UNBIND 10 secs later
04-06 12:32:30.221  Samsung SM-T365Y    Debug   997 PackageManager  remove MCS_UNBIND message and Posting MCS_UNBIND 10 secs later
04-06 12:32:30.221  Samsung SM-T365Y    Error   359 installd    system dir 0 : /system/app/
04-06 12:32:30.211  Samsung SM-T365Y    Debug   1749    AndroidRuntime  Shutting down VM
04-06 12:32:30.211  Samsung SM-T365Y    Error   359 installd    system dir 1 : /system/priv-app/
04-06 12:32:30.211  Samsung SM-T365Y    Error   359 installd    system dir 0 : /system/app/
Force stopping service ServiceRecord{37da9746 u0 _tablet.toms_app_tablet/md5b3576f19b55fa497040f1ea60a29f1ae.FloatingMeterService}
04-06 12:32:30.201  Samsung SM-T365Y    Debug   1749    AndroidRuntime  Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
04-06 12:32:30.201  Samsung SM-T365Y    Info    997 ActivityManager Force stopping toms_app_tablet.toms_app_tablet appid=10165 user=0: from pid 1749
Force finishing activity 3 ActivityRecord{12717f11 u0 toms_app_tablet.toms_app_tablet/md5dc5ad32ea713dd0841d86c7c17d74757.MainActivityView t43}
Force finishing activity 3 ActivityRecord{284ded07 u0 toms_app_tablet.toms_app_tablet/md5dc5ad32ea713dd0841d86c7c17d74757.SoftMeterView t44}
04-06 12:32:30.201  Samsung SM-T365Y    Debug   997 PackageManager  remove MCS_UNBIND message and Posting MCS_UNBIND 10 secs later
04-06 12:32:30.191  Samsung SM-T365Y    Debug   997 PackageManager  remove MCS_UNBIND message and Posting MCS_UNBIND 10 secs later
04-06 12:32:30.191  Samsung SM-T365Y    Error   359 installd    system dir 0 : /system/app/
04-06 12:32:30.181  Samsung SM-T365Y    Error   359 installd    this /system/container/KnoxBBCProvider/KnoxBBCProvider.apk also system apk
04-06 12:32:30.181  Samsung SM-T365Y    Error   359 installd    system dir 1 : /system/priv-app/
04-06 12:32:30.181  Samsung SM-T365Y    Error   359 installd    system dir 3 : /oem/app/
04-06 12:32:30.181  Samsung SM-T365Y    Error   359 installd    system dir 0 : /system/app/
04-06 12:32:30.181  Samsung SM-T365Y    Error   359 installd    system dir 2 : /vendor/app/
04-06 12:32:30.181  Samsung SM-T365Y    Debug   1303    Recents_RecentsTaskLoader   getAndUpdateThumbnail getTaskThumbnail
04-06 12:32:30.181  Samsung SM-T365Y    Debug   997 PackageManager  remove MCS_UNBIND message and Posting MCS_UNBIND 10 secs later
04-06 12:32:30.171  Samsung SM-T365Y    Warning 1303    ResourceType    No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000
04-06 12:32:30.171  Samsung SM-T365Y    Warning 1303    PackageManager  Failure retrieving resources for com.android.settings: Resource ID #0x0
04-06 12:32:30.161  Samsung SM-T365Y    Debug   997 PackageManager  remove MCS_UNBIND message and Posting MCS_UNBIND 10 secs later
04-06 12:32:30.161  Samsung SM-T365Y    Error   1749    AffinityControl AffinityControl: registerfunction enter
04-06 12:32:30.161  Samsung SM-T365Y    Error   359 installd    system dir 0 : /system/app/
04-06 12:32:30.151  Samsung SM-T365Y    Error   359 installd    system dir 0 : /system/app/
04-06 12:32:30.151  Samsung SM-T365Y    Debug   997 PackageManager  remove MCS_UNBIND message and Posting MCS_UNBIND 10 secs later
04-06 12:32:30.151  Samsung SM-T365Y    Error   359 installd    system dir 1 : /system/priv-app/
04-06 12:32:30.141  Samsung SM-T365Y    Error   359 installd    system dir 0 : /system/app/
04-06 12:32:30.141  Samsung SM-T365Y    Error   359 installd    system dir 1 : /system/priv-app/
04-06 12:32:30.141  Samsung SM-T365Y    Debug   997 PackageManager  remove MCS_UNBIND message and Posting MCS_UNBIND 10 secs later
04-06 12:32:30.131  Samsung SM-T365Y    Debug   997 PackageManager  remove MCS_UNBIND message and Posting MCS_UNBIND 10 secs later
04-06 12:32:30.131  Samsung SM-T365Y    Error   359 installd    system dir 0 : /system/app/
04-06 12:32:30.121  Samsung SM-T365Y    Debug   997 PackageManager  remove MCS_UNBIND message and Posting MCS_UNBIND 10 secs later
04-06 12:32:30.121  Samsung SM-T365Y    Error   359 installd    system dir 0 : /system/app/
04-06 12:32:30.121  Samsung SM-T365Y    Error   359 installd    system dir 1 : /system/priv-app/
04-06 12:32:30.111  Samsung SM-T365Y    Error   359 installd    system dir 1 : /system/priv-app/
04-06 12:32:30.111  Samsung SM-T365Y    Error   359 installd    system dir 0 : /system/app/
04-06 12:32:30.111  Samsung SM-T365Y    Debug   997 PackageManager  remove MCS_UNBIND message and Posting MCS_UNBIND 10 secs later
04-06 12:32:30.101  Samsung SM-T365Y    Error   359 installd    system dir 0 : /system/app/
04-06 12:32:30.101  Samsung SM-T365Y    Debug   997 PackageManager  remove MCS_UNBIND message and Posting MCS_UNBIND 10 secs later
04-06 12:32:30.101  Samsung SM-T365Y    Debug   997 PackageManager  remove MCS_UNBIND message and Posting MCS_UNBIND 10 secs later
04-06 12:32:30.101  Samsung SM-T365Y    Error   359 installd    system dir 0 : /system/app/
04-06 12:32:30.091  Samsung SM-T365Y    Info    1918    MultiWindowTrayInfo updateAppListItemState
04-06 12:32:30.081  Samsung SM-T365Y    Error   359 installd    system dir 0 : /system/app/
04-06 12:32:30.081  Samsung SM-T365Y    Error   359 installd    system dir 1 : /system/priv-app/
04-06 12:32:30.081  Samsung SM-T365Y    Info    1918    MultiWindowTrayInfo updateAppListItemState
04-06 12:32:30.071  Samsung SM-T365Y    Debug   997 PackageManager  remove MCS_UNBIND message and Posting MCS_UNBIND 10 secs later
04-06 12:32:30.071  Samsung SM-T365Y    Info    1918    MultiWindowTrayInfo updateAppListItemState
04-06 12:32:30.071  Samsung SM-T365Y    Info    1918    MultiWindowTrayInfo updateAppListItemState
04-06 12:32:30.071  Samsung SM-T365Y    Error   359 installd    system dir 0 : /system/app/
04-06 12:32:30.061  Samsung SM-T365Y    Debug   997 PackageManager  remove MCS_UNBIND message and Posting MCS_UNBIND 10 secs later
04-06 12:32:30.051  Samsung SM-T365Y    Info    1918    MultiWindowTrayInfo updateAppListItemState
04-06 12:32:30.051  Samsung SM-T365Y    Debug   997 PackageManager  remove MCS_UNBIND message and Posting MCS_UNBIND 10 secs later
04-06 12:32:30.051  Samsung SM-T365Y    Info    1918    MultiWindowTrayInfo updateAppListItemState
04-06 12:32:30.051  Samsung SM-T365Y    Error   359 installd    system dir 0 : /system/app/
04-06 12:32:30.051  Samsung SM-T365Y    Error   359 installd    system dir 1 : /system/priv-app/
04-06 12:32:30.041  Samsung SM-T365Y    Info    1918    MultiWindowTrayInfo updateAppListItemState
04-06 12:32:30.031  Samsung SM-T365Y    Info    1918    MultiWindowTrayInfo updateAppListItemState
04-06 12:32:30.031  Samsung SM-T365Y    Info    1918    MultiWindowTrayInfo updateAppListItemState
04-06 12:32:30.021  Samsung SM-T365Y    Error   359 installd    system dir 0 : /system/app/
04-06 12:32:30.021  Samsung SM-T365Y    Info    1918    MultiWindowTrayInfo updateAppListItemState
04-06 12:32:30.011  Samsung SM-T365Y    Info    1918    MultiWindowTrayInfo updateAppListItemState
04-06 12:32:30.011  Samsung SM-T365Y    Info    1918    MultiWindowTrayInfo updateAppListItemState
04-06 12:32:30.001  Samsung SM-T365Y    Info    1918    MultiWindowTrayInfo updateAppListItemState
04-06 12:32:30.001  Samsung SM-T365Y    Info    1918    MultiWindowTrayInfo updateAppListItemState
04-06 12:32:29.991  Samsung SM-T365Y    Debug   997 PackageManager  remove MCS_UNBIND message and Posting MCS_UNBIND 10 secs later
04-06 12:32:29.991  Samsung SM-T365Y    Info    1918    MultiWindowTrayInfo updateAppListItemState
04-06 12:32:29.981  Samsung SM-T365Y    Info    1918    MultiWindowTrayInfo updateAppListItemState
04-06 12:32:29.981  Samsung SM-T365Y    Info    1918    MultiWindowTrayInfo updateAppListItemState
04-06 12:32:29.971  Samsung SM-T365Y    Error   359 installd    system dir 1 : /system/priv-app/
04-06 12:32:29.971  Samsung SM-T365Y    Debug   997 PackageManager  remove MCS_UNBIND message and Posting MCS_UNBIND 10 secs later
04-06 12:32:29.971  Samsung SM-T365Y    Info    1918    MultiWindowTrayInfo updateAppListItemState
04-06 12:32:29.971  Samsung SM-T365Y    Error   359 installd    system dir 0 : /system/app/
04-06 12:32:29.961  Samsung SM-T365Y    Info    1918    MultiWindowTrayInfo updateAppListItemState
04-06 12:32:29.951  Samsung SM-T365Y    Info    1918    MultiWindowTrayInfo updateAppListItemState
04-06 12:32:29.941  Samsung SM-T365Y    Info    1918    MultiWindowTrayInfo updateAppListItemState
04-06 12:32:29.931  Samsung SM-T365Y    Debug   1749    AndroidRuntime  readGMSProperty: already setted!!
04-06 12:32:29.931  Samsung SM-T365Y    Debug   1749    AndroidRuntime  propertySet: couldn't set property (it is from app)
04-06 12:32:29.931  Samsung SM-T365Y    Debug   1749    AndroidRuntime  CheckJNI is OFF
04-06 12:32:29.931  Samsung SM-T365Y    Debug   1749    AndroidRuntime  readGMSProperty: end
04-06 12:32:29.931  Samsung SM-T365Y    Debug   1749    AndroidRuntime  addProductProperty: start
04-06 12:32:29.931  Samsung SM-T365Y    Debug   1749    AndroidRuntime  readGMSProperty: start
04-06 12:32:29.931  Samsung SM-T365Y    Error   359 installd    system dir 1 : /system/priv-app/
04-06 12:32:29.931  Samsung SM-T365Y    Debug   1749    AndroidRuntime  readGMSProperty: could not set the property(default)!!
04-06 12:32:29.931  Samsung SM-T365Y    Info    1918    MultiWindowTrayInfo updateAppListItemState
04-06 12:32:29.931  Samsung SM-T365Y    Error   359 installd    system dir 0 : /system/app/
04-06 12:32:29.921  Samsung SM-T365Y    Debug   997 PackageManager  remove MCS_UNBIND message and Posting MCS_UNBIND 10 secs later
04-06 12:32:29.921  Samsung SM-T365Y    Debug   1749    AndroidRuntime  >>>>>> START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit uid 2000 <<<<<<
04-06 12:32:29.911  Samsung SM-T365Y    Info    1918    MultiWindowTrayInfo updateAppListItemState
04-06 12:32:29.911  Samsung SM-T365Y    Info    1918    MultiWindowTrayInfo updateAppListItemState
04-06 12:32:29.901  Samsung SM-T365Y    Info    1918    MultiWindowTrayInfo updateAppListItemState
04-06 12:32:29.901  Samsung SM-T365Y    Info    1918    MultiWindowTrayInfo updateAppListItemState
04-06 12:32:29.901  Samsung SM-T365Y    Info    1918    MultiWindowTrayInfo getAppCnt
04-06 12:32:29.891  Samsung SM-T365Y    Info    314 SurfaceFlinger  id=513 Removed  (-2/11)
04-06 12:32:29.891  Samsung SM-T365Y    Info    1918    MultiWindowTrayInfo getAppCnt
04-06 12:32:29.881  Samsung SM-T365Y    Error   359 installd    system dir 0 : /system/app/
04-06 12:32:29.881  Samsung SM-T365Y    Info    314 SurfaceFlinger  id=513 Removed  (8/11)
04-06 12:32:29.881  Samsung SM-T365Y    Info    314 SurfaceFlinger  id=513 Removed  (-2/11)
04-06 12:32:29.881  Samsung SM-T365Y    Info    1918    MultiWindowTrayInfo getAppCnt
04-06 12:32:29.881  Samsung SM-T365Y    Info    1918    MultiWindowTrayInfo getAppCnt
04-06 12:32:29.881  Samsung SM-T365Y    Error   359 installd    system dir 1 : /system/priv-app/
04-06 12:32:29.871  Samsung SM-T365Y    Info    1918    MultiWindowTrayInfo getAppCnt
04-06 12:32:29.871  Samsung SM-T365Y    Debug   997 PackageManager  remove MCS_UNBIND message and Posting MCS_UNBIND 10 secs later
04-06 12:32:29.871  Samsung SM-T365Y    Info    1918    MultiWindowTrayInfo getAppCnt
04-06 12:32:29.871  Samsung SM-T365Y    Info    1918    MultiWindowTrayInfo getAppCnt
04-06 12:32:29.841  Samsung SM-T365Y    Info    997 Timeline    Timeline: Activity_windows_visible id: ActivityRecord{239e2596 u0 com.android.systemui/.recents.RecentsActivity t5} time:74959891
04-06 12:32:29.841  Samsung SM-T365Y    Debug   997 CustomFrequencyManagerService   acquireDVFSLockLocked : type : DVFS_MIN_LIMIT  frequency : 1190400  uid : 1000  pid : 997  pkgName : ACTIVITY_RESUME_BOOSTER@12
04-06 12:32:29.841  Samsung SM-T365Y    Error   359 installd    system dir 0 : /system/app/
04-06 12:32:29.831  Samsung SM-T365Y    Debug   997 CustomFrequencyManagerService   releaseDVFSLockLocked : Getting Lock type frm List : DVFS_MIN_LIMIT  frequency : 1190400  uid : 1000  pid : 997  tag : ACTIVITY_RESUME_BOOSTER@6
04-06 12:32:29.831  Samsung SM-T365Y    Debug   997 ActivityManager mDVFSHelper.release()
04-06 12:32:29.821  Samsung SM-T365Y    Info    314 SurfaceFlinger  id=527 Removed uhumbnail a (-2/12)
04-06 12:32:29.821  Samsung SM-T365Y    Info    314 SurfaceFlinger  id=524 Removed Tettings (-2/13)
04-06 12:32:29.821  Samsung SM-T365Y    Info    314 SurfaceFlinger  id=524 Removed Tettings (7/13)
04-06 12:32:29.821  Samsung SM-T365Y    Debug   997 PackageManager  remove MCS_UNBIND message and Posting MCS_UNBIND 10 secs later
04-06 12:32:29.821  Samsung SM-T365Y    Info    314 SurfaceFlinger  id=527 Removed uhumbnail a (7/12)
04-06 12:32:29.811  Samsung SM-T365Y    Error   359 installd    system dir 0 : /system/app/
04-06 12:32:29.801  Samsung SM-T365Y    Debug   997 PackageManager  remove MCS_UNBIND message and Posting MCS_UNBIND 10 secs later
04-06 12:32:29.801  Samsung SM-T365Y    Debug   997 PackageManager  remove MCS_UNBIND message and Posting MCS_UNBIND 10 secs later
04-06 12:32:29.801  Samsung SM-T365Y    Error   359 installd    system dir 0 : /system/app/
04-06 12:32:29.801  Samsung SM-T365Y    Error   359 installd    system dir 1 : /system/priv-app/
04-06 12:32:29.791  Samsung SM-T365Y    Debug   997 PackageManager  remove MCS_UNBIND message and Posting MCS_UNBIND 10 secs later
04-06 12:32:29.791  Samsung SM-T365Y    Error   359 installd    system dir 0 : /system/app/
04-06 12:32:29.781  Samsung SM-T365Y    Error   359 installd    system dir 0 : /system/app/
04-06 12:32:29.781  Samsung SM-T365Y    Debug   997 PackageManager  remove MCS_UNBIND message and Posting MCS_UNBIND 10 secs later
04-06 12:32:29.771  Samsung SM-T365Y    Error   359 installd    system dir 0 : /system/app/
04-06 12:32:29.771  Samsung SM-T365Y    Debug   997 PackageManager  remove MCS_UNBIND message and Posting MCS_UNBIND 10 secs later
04-06 12:32:29.771  Samsung SM-T365Y    Error   359 installd    system dir 1 : /system/priv-app/
04-06 12:32:29.761  Samsung SM-T365Y    Error   359 installd    system dir 3 : /oem/app/
04-06 12:32:29.761  Samsung SM-T365Y    Error   359 installd    system dir 0 : /system/app/
04-06 12:32:29.761  Samsung SM-T365Y    Error   359 installd    system dir 2 : /vendor/app/
04-06 12:32:29.761  Samsung SM-T365Y    Debug   997 PackageManager  remove MCS_UNBIND message and Posting MCS_UNBIND 10 secs later
04-06 12:32:29.761  Samsung SM-T365Y    Error   359 installd    system dir 1 : /system/priv-app/
04-06 12:32:29.761  Samsung SM-T365Y    Error   359 installd    this /system/container/ContainerAgent2/ContainerAgent2.apk also system apk
04-06 12:32:29.751  Samsung SM-T365Y    Error   359 installd    system dir 1 : /system/priv-app/
04-06 12:32:29.751  Samsung SM-T365Y    Error   359 installd    system dir 0 : /system/app/
04-06 12:32:29.751  Samsung SM-T365Y    Debug   997 PackageManager  remove MCS_UNBIND message and Posting MCS_UNBIND 10 secs later
04-06 12:32:29.741  Samsung SM-T365Y    Error   359 installd    system dir 1 : /system/priv-app/
04-06 12:32:29.741  Samsung SM-T365Y    Error   359 installd    system dir 0 : /system/app/
04-06 12:32:29.731  Samsung SM-T365Y    Error   359 installd    system dir 0 : /system/app/
04-06 12:32:29.731  Samsung SM-T365Y    Debug   997 PackageManager  remove MCS_UNBIND message and Posting MCS_UNBIND 10 secs later
04-06 12:32:29.731  Samsung SM-T365Y    Error   359 installd    system dir 1 : /system/priv-app/
04-06 12:32:29.721  Samsung SM-T365Y    Debug   997 PackageManager  remove MCS_UNBIND message and Posting MCS_UNBIND 10 secs later
04-06 12:32:29.721  Samsung SM-T365Y    Debug   997 PackageManager  remove MCS_UNBIND message and Posting MCS_UNBIND 10 secs later
04-06 12:32:29.721  Samsung SM-T365Y    Error   359 installd    system dir 0 : /system/app/
04-06 12:32:29.701  Samsung SM-T365Y    Verbose 997 GpsLocationProvider reportStatus status: 2
04-06 12:32:29.701  Samsung SM-T365Y    Debug   997 PackageManager  remove MCS_UNBIND message and Posting MCS_UNBIND 10 secs later
04-06 12:32:29.701  Samsung SM-T365Y    Error   359 installd    system dir 0 : /system/app/
04-06 12:32:29.701  Samsung SM-T365Y    Error   997 LocSvc_ApiV02   I/<--- void globalEventCb(locClientHandleType, uint32_t, locClientEventIndUnionType, void*) line 99 QMI_LOC_EVENT_ENGINE_STATE_IND_V02
04-06 12:32:29.701  Samsung SM-T365Y    Error   359 installd    system dir 1 : /system/priv-app/
04-06 12:32:29.701  Samsung SM-T365Y    Verbose 997 GpsLocationProvider reportStatus status: 4
04-06 12:32:29.691  Samsung SM-T365Y    Debug   997 GpsLocationProvider send an intent to notify GPS has been enabled or disabled mNavigating = false
onReceive: action = android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE, gpsEnabled = false
onReceive: cancel noti
04-06 12:32:29.691  Samsung SM-T365Y    Verbose 997 GpsLocationProvider reportStatus status: 2
04-06 12:32:29.691  Samsung SM-T365Y    Error   997 LocSvc_ApiV02   I/<--- void globalEventCb(locClientHandleType, uint32_t, locClientEventIndUnionType, void*) line 99 QMI_LOC_EVENT_POSITION_REPORT_IND_V02
04-06 12:32:29.691  Samsung SM-T365Y    Debug   997 GpsLocationProvider stopNavigating
04-06 12:32:29.691  Samsung SM-T365Y    Debug   997 StatusBarManagerService removeIcon slot=location
04-06 12:32:29.691  Samsung SM-T365Y    Debug   997 GpsLocationProvider setRequest ProviderRequest[OFF]
04-06 12:32:29.691  Samsung SM-T365Y    Debug   1238    PhoneStatusBar  removeIcon slot=location index=12 viewIndex=2
04-06 12:32:29.681  Samsung SM-T365Y    Debug   997 PackageManager  remove MCS_UNBIND message and Posting MCS_UNBIND 10 secs later
04-06 12:32:29.681  Samsung SM-T365Y    Error   359 installd    system dir 0 : /system/app/
04-06 12:32:29.671  Samsung SM-T365Y    Error   359 installd    system dir 0 : /system/app/
04-06 12:32:29.671  Samsung SM-T365Y    Info    997 ActivityManager Process com.samsung.SMT (pid 29631)(adj 0) has died(144,380)
04-06 12:32:29.671  Samsung SM-T365Y    Error   359 installd    system dir 1 : /system/priv-app/
04-06 12:32:29.671  Samsung SM-T365Y    Debug   997 PackageManager  remove MCS_UNBIND message and Posting MCS_UNBIND 10 secs later
04-06 12:32:29.661  Samsung SM-T365Y    Error   359 installd    system dir 0 : /system/app/
04-06 12:32:29.661  Samsung SM-T365Y    Debug   997 PackageManager  remove MCS_UNBIND message and Posting MCS_UNBIND 10 secs later
04-06 12:32:29.641  Samsung SM-T365Y    Info    357 OMXCodec    [OMX.SEC.mp3.dec] Now Idle. Component sends idle done Event
04-06 12:32:29.641  Samsung SM-T365Y    Info    29631   AndroidRuntime  VM exiting with result code 0, cleanup skipped.
04-06 12:32:29.641  Samsung SM-T365Y    Info    357 SEC_BASE_COMP   SEC_OMX_ComponentStateSet: Cur(2) -> Dest(1)
04-06 12:32:29.641  Samsung SM-T365Y    Info    357 SecMediaClock   SecMediaClock destructor
04-06 12:32:29.641  Samsung SM-T365Y    Info    357 OMXCodec    [OMX.SEC.mp3.dec] stop mState=4
04-06 12:32:29.641  Samsung SM-T365Y    Info    357 SEC_BASE_COMP   SEC_OMX_ComponentStateSet: Cur(3) -> Dest(2)
04-06 12:32:29.621  Samsung SM-T365Y    Info    357 SEC_BASE_COMP   SEC_OMX_ComponentStateSet: Cur(2) -> Dest(1)
04-06 12:32:29.621  Samsung SM-T365Y    Info    357 OMXCodec    [OMX.SEC.mp3.dec] stopOmxComponent_l() mstate = 1
04-06 12:32:29.621  Samsung SM-T365Y    Info    357 OMXCodec    [OMX.SEC.mp3.dec] Now Idle. Component sends idle done Event
04-06 12:32:29.621  Samsung SM-T365Y    Info    357 OMXCodec    [OMX.SEC.mp3.dec] stop() sendCommand(0xf8, OMX_CommandStateSet, OMX_StateIdle)
04-06 12:32:29.621  Samsung SM-T365Y    Debug   29631   SamsungTTS  onDestroy()
04-06 12:32:29.621  Samsung SM-T365Y    Info    357 OMXCodec    [OMX.SEC.mp3.dec] stop mState=4
04-06 12:32:29.621  Samsung SM-T365Y    Info    357 SecMediaClock   SecMediaClock destructor
04-06 12:32:29.611  Samsung SM-T365Y    Verbose 357 AudioSink   --- close
04-06 12:32:29.611  Samsung SM-T365Y    Info    357 SecVideoCapture reset
04-06 12:32:29.611  Samsung SM-T365Y    Info    357 SecVideoCapture SecVideoCapture destructor
04-06 12:32:29.611  Samsung SM-T365Y    Warning 997 InputDispatcher Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel
04-06 12:32:29.611  Samsung SM-T365Y    Info    997 WindowState WIN DEATH: Window{34fdebd7 u0 d0 toms_app_tablet.toms_app_tablet}
04-06 12:32:29.611  Samsung SM-T365Y    Verbose 357 StagefrightPlayer   reset
04-06 12:32:29.611  Samsung SM-T365Y    Verbose 357 AwesomePlayer   mSecCapture clear
04-06 12:32:29.611  Samsung SM-T365Y    Verbose 357 MediaPlayerService  Client(110) destructor pid = 474
04-06 12:32:29.611  Samsung SM-T365Y    Info    357 SecMediaClock   SecMediaClock destructor
04-06 12:32:29.601  Samsung SM-T365Y    Info    357 SEC_BASE_COMP   SEC_OMX_ComponentStateSet: Cur(3) -> Dest(2)
04-06 12:32:29.601  Samsung SM-T365Y    Info    357 SEC_BASE_COMP   SEC_OMX_ComponentStateSet: Cur(2) -> Dest(1)
04-06 12:32:29.601  Samsung SM-T365Y    Info    357 OMXCodec    [OMX.SEC.mp3.dec] Now Idle. Component sends idle done Event
04-06 12:32:29.601  Samsung SM-T365Y    Info    357 OMXCodec    [OMX.SEC.mp3.dec] stop() sendCommand(0xf7, OMX_CommandStateSet, OMX_StateIdle)
04-06 12:32:29.601  Samsung SM-T365Y    Verbose 357 AwesomePlayer   reset_l() mAudioPlayer successfully deleted
04-06 12:32:29.591  Samsung SM-T365Y    Info    357 OMXCodec    [OMX.SEC.mp3.dec] stop() sendCommand(0xf6, OMX_CommandStateSet, OMX_StateIdle)
04-06 12:32:29.591  Samsung SM-T365Y    Info    357 OMXCodec    [OMX.SEC.mp3.dec] stop mState=4
04-06 12:32:29.591  Samsung SM-T365Y    Verbose 357 AwesomePlayer   mSecMediaClock clear
04-06 12:32:29.591  Samsung SM-T365Y    Info    357 SecMediaClock   SecMediaClock destructor
04-06 12:32:29.591  Samsung SM-T365Y    Info    357 OMXCodec    [OMX.SEC.mp3.dec] stopOmxComponent_l() mstate = 1
04-06 12:32:29.591  Samsung SM-T365Y    Verbose 357 AwesomePlayer   mSecMediaClock clear
04-06 12:32:29.591  Samsung SM-T365Y    Info    357 SecVideoCapture reset
04-06 12:32:29.591  Samsung SM-T365Y    Info    357 OMXCodec    [OMX.SEC.mp3.dec] Now Idle. Component sends idle done Event
04-06 12:32:29.591  Samsung SM-T365Y    Verbose 357 AwesomePlayer   reset_l() mAudioPlayer successfully deleted
04-06 12:32:29.591  Samsung SM-T365Y    Verbose 357 AwesomePlayer   mAudioTrackVector clear
04-06 12:32:29.591  Samsung SM-T365Y    Info    357 SEC_BASE_COMP   SEC_OMX_ComponentStateSet: Cur(2) -> Dest(1)
04-06 12:32:29.591  Samsung SM-T365Y    Info    357 SEC_BASE_COMP   SEC_OMX_ComponentStateSet: Cur(3) -> Dest(2)
04-06 12:32:29.591  Samsung SM-T365Y    Verbose 357 StagefrightPlayer   ~StagefrightPlayer
04-06 12:32:29.591  Samsung SM-T365Y    Verbose 357 StagefrightPlayer   reset
04-06 12:32:29.591  Samsung SM-T365Y    Info    997 WindowState WIN DEATH: Window{3fb8cae2 u0 d0 toms_app_tablet.toms_app_tablet/md5dc5ad32ea713dd0841d86c7c17d74757.SoftMeterView}
04-06 12:32:29.591  Samsung SM-T365Y    Info    357 SecVideoCapture SecVideoCapture destructor
04-06 12:32:29.581  Samsung SM-T365Y    Warning 997 ActivityManager Scheduling restart of crashed service toms_app_tablet.toms_app_tablet/md5b3576f19b55fa497040f1ea60a29f1ae.FloatingMeterService in 1000ms
04-06 12:32:29.581  Samsung SM-T365Y    Verbose 357 AudioSink   --- close
04-06 12:32:29.581  Samsung SM-T365Y    Verbose 357 MediaPlayerService  Client(108) destructor pid = 474
04-06 12:32:29.581  Samsung SM-T365Y    Verbose 357 StagefrightPlayer   reset
04-06 12:32:29.581  Samsung SM-T365Y    Verbose 357 AudioSink   +++ close
04-06 12:32:29.571  Samsung SM-T365Y    Error   359 installd    system dir 1 : /system/priv-app/
04-06 12:32:29.571  Samsung SM-T365Y    Error   997 InputDispatcher channel ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
04-06 12:32:29.571  Samsung SM-T365Y    Verbose 357 AwesomePlayer   cancelPlayerEvents (keepNotifications=0)
04-06 12:32:29.571  Samsung SM-T365Y    Error   359 installd    system dir 0 : /system/app/
04-06 12:32:29.571  Samsung SM-T365Y    Warning 997 InputDispatcher channel ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
04-06 12:32:29.571  Samsung SM-T365Y    Verbose 357 AwesomePlayer   notifyListner_l() msg (8-MEDIA_STOPPED), ext1 (0), ext2 (0)
04-06 12:32:29.571  Samsung SM-T365Y    Verbose 357 AwesomePlayer   reset_l()
04-06 12:32:29.571  Samsung SM-T365Y    Verbose 357 AwesomePlayer   mSecMediaClock clear
04-06 12:32:29.561  Samsung SM-T365Y    Info    357 OMXCodec    [OMX.SEC.mp3.dec] stopOmxComponent_l() mstate = 1
04-06 12:32:29.561  Samsung SM-T365Y    Info    357 SEC_BASE_COMP   SEC_OMX_ComponentStateSet: Cur(3) -> Dest(2)
04-06 12:32:29.561  Samsung SM-T365Y    Verbose 357 AwesomePlayer   notifyListner_l() msg (8-MEDIA_STOPPED), ext1 (0), ext2 (0)
04-06 12:32:29.561  Samsung SM-T365Y    Verbose 357 StagefrightPlayer   ~StagefrightPlayer
04-06 12:32:29.561  Samsung SM-T365Y    Info    357 OMXCodec    [OMX.SEC.mp3.dec] stop() sendCommand(0xf5, OMX_CommandStateSet, OMX_StateIdle)
04-06 12:32:29.561  Samsung SM-T365Y    Verbose 357 AwesomePlayer   reset_l()
04-06 12:32:29.561  Samsung SM-T365Y    Info    357 SecMediaClock   SecMediaClock destructor
04-06 12:32:29.561  Samsung SM-T365Y    Info    357 OMXCodec    [OMX.SEC.mp3.dec] Now Idle. Component sends idle done Event
04-06 12:32:29.561  Samsung SM-T365Y    Info    357 SecVideoCapture reset
04-06 12:32:29.561  Samsung SM-T365Y    Debug   997 PackageManager  remove MCS_UNBIND message and Posting MCS_UNBIND 10 secs later
04-06 12:32:29.561  Samsung SM-T365Y    Verbose 357 AwesomePlayer   mSecMediaClock clear
04-06 12:32:29.561  Samsung SM-T365Y    Info    357 SecVideoCapture SecVideoCapture destructor
04-06 12:32:29.561  Samsung SM-T365Y    Verbose 357 StagefrightPlayer   reset
04-06 12:32:29.561  Samsung SM-T365Y    Info    357 SEC_BASE_COMP   SEC_OMX_ComponentStateSet: Cur(2) -> Dest(1)
04-06 12:32:29.561  Samsung SM-T365Y    Info    997 WindowState WIN DEATH: Window{466a571 u0 d0 toms_app_tablet.toms_app_tablet}
04-06 12:32:29.561  Samsung SM-T365Y    Verbose 357 AwesomePlayer   reset_l() mAudioPlayer successfully deleted
04-06 12:32:29.561  Samsung SM-T365Y    Verbose 357 AwesomePlayer   mSecCapture clear
04-06 12:32:29.551  Samsung SM-T365Y    Debug   997 LocationManagerService  Location listener died
04-06 12:32:29.551  Samsung SM-T365Y    Verbose 357 AwesomePlayer   mAudioTrackVector clear
04-06 12:32:29.551  Samsung SM-T365Y    Verbose 357 MediaPlayerService  Client(107) destructor pid = 474
04-06 12:32:29.551  Samsung SM-T365Y    Info    357 OMXCodec    [OMX.SEC.mp3.dec] stop mState=4
04-06 12:32:29.551  Samsung SM-T365Y    Verbose 357 StagefrightPlayer   reset
04-06 12:32:29.551  Samsung SM-T365Y    Info    997 WindowState WIN DEATH: Window{37670ef5 u0 d0 toms_app_tablet.toms_app_tablet/md5dc5ad32ea713dd0841d86c7c17d74757.MainActivityView}
04-06 12:32:29.551  Samsung SM-T365Y    Info    997 LocationManagerService  remove 2d2a9afb by toms_app_tablet.toms_app_tablet
04-06 12:32:29.551  Samsung SM-T365Y    Debug   357 AudioFlinger    purging stale effects --
04-06 12:32:29.551  Samsung SM-T365Y    Verbose 357 MediaPlayerService  disconnect(107) from pid 474
04-06 12:32:29.541  Samsung SM-T365Y    Error   359 installd    system dir 1 : /system/priv-app/
```

Comment: I see your `FloatingMeterService` is being restarted and then killed, and  `MainActivityView`, `SoftMeterView` are also being killed off. So the question I would start with: what, if anything, are you processing in the service, CPU intensive? stuck in a loop? does your service try to update the  activities in the background, do you hold references from your service to maybe a singleton that is ref'd to your activities causing a rapid cyclic fault path in your app, etc...

Comment: If your app is not really sucking up CPU in the background (remember **EVERYTHING** runs on the main looper thread unless you spin up a task/thread/runnable), I would *assume* you *might* have a memory leak and the OS is killing your app to maintain a min. free memory level....

Comment: thank you for thinking along. So the service gets restarted and killed first ? the FloatingMeterService is only there because we wanted a floating window over the top of everything. There is hardly any processing done in there.. but i'll see if i can check if there is any lock or so.. i checked the              _JavaRuntime.MaxMemory() : 537 Meg
_JavaRuntime.TotalMemory() - _JavaRuntime.FreeMemory() : 26 Meg ...and it hardly moves..

Comment: The funny thing is that it only happens during when the Task Manager is visible with all the other windows..

Comment: Could just be the OS doing a low memory sweep. Also you can log memory overrides to logcat, such as `OnTrimMemory` and `OnLowMemory`

Comment: added the IComponentCallbacks2 handler to all of the Activities, and besides OnTrimMemory (TrimMemory.UIHidden ) none of them get called. None of them get called before the killing of the app either.. This is a hard one to nail down.

Comment: found a machine that has Visual Studio Enterprise so i can run the Xamarin profiler. Seeing that the OS is not telling me why the app is being killed, how would i go abouts identifying what is causing it ? If i run the profiler with all instrumentation Xamarin Profiler crashes right after the application crashes. I can select individual Allocations,Cycles, Memory, Performance or Time profiler.. Have gone through all of these, but can't see any threads particularly busy just before the OS kills it.. Any tips on how to identify the problem from here ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found a solution.
The App wasn't using a lot of processor time/memory or even received a IComponentCallbacks2
Used the Xamarin Profiler and it also didn't show any overuse/issue.

I noticed that the App/Service only got killed when it was 3rd in line (in the android Task Manager) or further on this particular tablet.

Added the StartForeground call inside the OnCreate of the service and i haven't seen the issue since.

If anyone knows why a service still gets cleaned up by Android (even if it is not misbehaving) i would like to know...