# Application getting killed when switching gifs

Tags: java, android, java-memory-leaks

I am writing an android application in which I want to switch between two gifs, when user click the gif image.

I have written the below code to switch between gifs.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    gifImageView = (GifImageView) findViewById(R.id.GifImageView);
    gifImageView.setGifImageResource(R.drawable.seat_animation0);

    gifImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            gifImageView.closeInputStream();

            animChange = !animChange;
            if(true == animChange) {
                gifImageView.setGifImageResource(R.drawable.seat_animation1);
            } else {
                gifImageView.setGifImageResource(R.drawable.seat_animation0);
            }

        }
    });

}
```

The code for "setGifImageResource" is

```
public void setGifImageResource(int id) {
    mInputStream = mContext.getResources().openRawResource(id);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    setFocusable(true);
    mMovie = Movie.decodeStream(mInputStream);
    mWidth = mMovie.width();
    mHeight = mMovie.height();

    requestLayout();
}
```

OnDraw method is as below

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    long now = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();

    if (mStart == 0) {
        mStart = now;
    }

    if (mMovie != null) {

        int duration = mMovie.duration();
        if (duration == 0) {
            duration = 1000;
        }

        int relTime = (int) ((now - mStart) % duration);

        mMovie.setTime(relTime);

        mMovie.draw(canvas, 0, 0);
        invalidate();
    }
}
```

The problem is when I keep on switching between the gifs for long time. The application crashes, but there is NO fatal error in the logs. Only i can see the below logs.

> 08-22 13:47:25.091  3704  3922 I WindowManager: WIN DEATH: Window{f737847d0 u0 com.jijith.gifanimation/com.jijith.gifanimation.MainActivity}
>   08-22 13:47:25.091  3704  3922 D WindowManager: disposeInputChannel mInputChannel: f737847 com.jijith.gifanimation/com.jijith.gifanimation.MainActivity (server)
>   08-22 13:47:25.091  3704  3878 W Looper  : Ignoring unexpected epoll events 0x19 on fd 407 that is no longer registered.
>   08-22 13:47:25.092  3704  4951 I ActivityManager: Process com.jijith.gifanimation (pid 27542) has died(2665,191)
>
> 08-22 13:47:25.093  3704  3878 D InputDispatcher: Waiting for application to become ready for input: 27542.  Reason: Waiting because the touched window's input channel is not registered with the input dispatcher.  The window may be in the process of being removed.
>   08-22 13:47:25.093  3704  3878 D InputDispatcher: failed to find connection ~ name='f737847 com.jijith.gifanimation/com.jijith.gifanimation.MainActivity (server)', fd='407', p='0x7d35b68420'
>
> 08-22 13:47:25.098  3704  4951 W ActivityManager: Force removing ActivityRecord{74e4a0ad0 u0 com.jijith.gifanimation/.MainActivity t195}: app died, no saved state
>
> 08-22 13:47:25.220  3704  4951 I WindowManager_SurfaceController: Destroying surface Surface(name=com.jijith.gifanimation/com.jijith.gifanimation.MainActivity) called by com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurface:2905 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurfaceLocked:1119 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.removeLocked:1860 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowInnerLocked:2928 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowLocked:2873 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowLocked:2683 com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.removeAllWindows:608 com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.removeAppFromTaskLocked:37

Comment: Have a look at the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13009659/4056108) for similar issue

Comment: Let me introduce u a good gif image viewer....it is for facebook and easy to use....check this out: [link](https://github.com/facebook/fresco)