# android + mysql + login

Tags: php, android, mysql, error-handling

i am creating a test for login proccess using php and mysql to connect to the database on android but i got in my log cat errors and on the emulator a force close can anyone help me with this??

## AndroidLogin.java

```
package com.sencide;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AndroidLogin extends Activity implements OnClickListener {


     Button ok,back,exit;
     TextView result;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

     // Login button clicked
        ok = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
        ok.setOnClickListener(this);

        result = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lbl_result);



    }



    public void postLoginData() {
        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
         Log.e("Responce-->","after httpclient");
        /* login.php returns true if username and password is equal to saranga */
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.64/login.php");
        Log.e("Responce-->","after httppost");
        try {
            // Add user name and password
         EditText uname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_username);
         String username = uname.getText().toString();

         EditText pword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_password);
         String password = pword.getText().toString();

            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            Log.e("Responce-->","after using the list name pair");

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            Log.w("SENCIDE", "Execute HTTP Post Request");
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            Log.e("Responce-->","after execute the http response");
          //  String str = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
            String str = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), HTTP.UTF_8);
            //Log.w("SENCIDE", str);

            Log.e("Responce-->",""+str);

            if(str.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("true"))
            {
             Log.w("SENCIDE", "TRUE");
             result.setText("Login successful");  
            }else
            {
             Log.w("SENCIDE", "FALSE");
             result.setText(str);            
            }

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } 



    private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        String line = "";
        StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
        // Wrap a BufferedReader around the InputStream
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        // Read response until the end
        try {
         while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
           total.append(line);
         }
        } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Return full string
        return total;
       }

        /* login.php returns true if username and password is equal to saranga */


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(view == ok){
             Thread t = new Thread(){
                    public void run(){
                        postLoginData();
                    }
                };
                t.start();

          }
    }





}
```

## log_cat

```
    04-03 06:38:32.182: E/Responce-->(1222): after httpclient
04-03 06:38:32.472: E/Responce-->(1222): after httppost
04-03 06:38:32.522: E/Responce-->(1222): after using the list name pair
04-03 06:38:32.522: W/SENCIDE(1222): Execute HTTP Post Request
04-03 06:38:49.141: E/Responce-->(1222): after httpclient
04-03 06:38:49.151: E/Responce-->(1222): after httppost
04-03 06:38:49.163: E/Responce-->(1222): after using the list name pair
04-03 06:38:49.163: W/SENCIDE(1222): Execute HTTP Post Request
04-03 06:38:49.324: E/Responce-->(1222): after httpclient
04-03 06:38:49.324: E/Responce-->(1222): after httppost
04-03 06:38:49.331: E/Responce-->(1222): after using the list name pair
04-03 06:38:49.331: W/SENCIDE(1222): Execute HTTP Post Request
04-03 06:38:51.662: E/Responce-->(1222): after httpclient
04-03 06:38:51.662: E/Responce-->(1222): after httppost
04-03 06:38:51.662: E/Responce-->(1222): after using the list name pair
04-03 06:38:51.662: W/SENCIDE(1222): Execute HTTP Post Request
04-03 06:38:52.742: E/Responce-->(1222): after httpclient
04-03 06:38:52.742: E/Responce-->(1222): after httppost
04-03 06:38:52.762: E/Responce-->(1222): after using the list name pair
04-03 06:38:52.762: W/SENCIDE(1222): Execute HTTP Post Request
```

## login.php

```
<?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username="root"; // Mysql username
$password="root"; // Mysql password
$db_name="testlogin"; // Database name
$tbl_name="members"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// username and password sent from form
$myusername=$_POST['username'];
$mypassword=$_POST['password'];

// To protect MySQL injection
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1){
echo "true";
}
else {
echo "Login Failed";
}
?>
```

Comment: export this file from DDMS-->File Explor. /data/anr/traces.txt

Answer (score 0):

your code is perfect just do:

if you are using above `3.0 android OS` then put this in `onCreate`

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

or you can use `AsyncTask` check this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Insted of this

```
String str = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
```

use

```
String str = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), HTTP.UTF_8);
```

Print log first check what you get

```
Log.e("Responce-->",""+str);
```

Comment: i still get in the log cat the error see the log cat above (i am new to android so i need help )

Comment: the log cat did not get to the Log.e("Responce-->",""+str); so i think the error is before this

Comment: ok i used the Strict mode and i got this in the log_cat and on the emulator a got a force close (see the log cat above)

Comment: you are getting keyDispatchingTimedOut so put your method in Async Task check this links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467205/android-key-dispatching-timed-out and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467205/android-key-dispatching-timed-out

Comment: ok sir i used the background thread but still can not get the correct response i think the error is in the execute hhtpresponse (edit the log_cat above and the android login.java)

Comment: @  Dhaval Sodha Parmaon the browser i get unable to connect and on the emulator browser i do not internet i can not get the internet to work on the emulator this is now another problem sorry for your time you had help me alot but now i will not bother you with this problem sorry

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the times in the log_cat (even the old one before you edited) it seems that the `httpclient.execute` call never comes back/times out.

Do the emulator have access to the login.php, and login.php is working correctly? 
Check with the Browser on the emulator

Beside that you should NOT do any time expensive stuff in the onClick handler.