# KeyDispatchTimedOut Error, when cliced a button to start an activity

Tags: java, android

I am trying to retrieve values from a column in SQLite table and store it in an array. I have to start that activity from a another activity by clicking a button. But unfortunately, when I click that button, I am getting KeyDisplatchTimedOut error, which stopped my application unexpectedly.

This is my logcat -

```
09-21 01:35:54.379: E/ActivityManager(1226): ANR in com.example.fromstart (com.example.fromstart/.Dialog)
09-21 01:35:54.379: E/ActivityManager(1226): Reason: keyDispatchingTimedOut
09-21 01:35:54.379: E/ActivityManager(1226): Load: 0.79 / 0.61 / 0.6
09-21 01:35:54.379: E/ActivityManager(1226): CPU usage from 5274ms to 0ms ago:
09-21 01:35:54.379: E/ActivityManager(1226):   94% 18598/com.example.fromstart: 93% user + 1.3% kernel
09-21 01:35:54.379: E/ActivityManager(1226):   1.8% 961/adbd: 0.1% user + 1.7% kernel / faults: 491 minor
09-21 01:35:54.379: E/ActivityManager(1226):   1.5% 951/surfaceflinger: 0.3% user + 1.1% kernel
09-21 01:35:54.379: E/ActivityManager(1226):   0.5% 1226/system_server: 0.1% user + 0.3% kernel / faults: 8 minor
09-21 01:35:54.379: E/ActivityManager(1226):   0% 943/yaffs-bg-1: 0% user + 0% kernel
09-21 01:35:54.379: E/ActivityManager(1226): 100% TOTAL: 94% user + 3.7% kernel + 1.3% softirq
09-21 01:35:54.379: E/ActivityManager(1226): CPU usage from 684ms to 1225ms later:
09-21 01:35:54.379: E/ActivityManager(1226):   96% 18598/com.example.fromstart: 96% user + 0% kernel
09-21 01:35:54.379: E/ActivityManager(1226):     96% 18598/ample.fromstart: 96% user + 0% kernel
09-21 01:35:54.379: E/ActivityManager(1226):   3.7% 1226/system_server: 0% user + 3.7% kernel
09-21 01:35:54.379: E/ActivityManager(1226):     3.7% 1243/ActivityManager: 0% user + 3.7% kernel
09-21 01:35:54.379: E/ActivityManager(1226): 100% TOTAL: 94% user + 5.4% kernel
09-21 01:35:54.409: D/dalvikvm(1226): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 162K, 32% free 7658K/11216K, paused 11ms, total 11ms
09-21 01:35:54.419: I/dalvikvm-heap(1226): Grow heap (frag case) to 8.748MB for 1127532-byte allocation
09-21 01:35:54.459: D/dalvikvm(1226): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 29% free 8759K/12320K, paused 42ms, total 42ms
09-21 01:35:54.589: D/(1226): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb8579720, tid 1243
09-21 01:36:02.879: W/ActivityManager(1226): Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord{b174f320 u0 com.example.fromstart/.MainActivity}
```

This is the way I am calling that activity -

activity1.java:

```
alert_menu = (Button) findViewById(R.id.alert_menu);
            alert_menu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(settings.this,Dialog.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                });
```

Dialog.java:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main_dup);

for(int i =1;i<=info.getrowcountofpersons();i++) 
{
    items[i-1]=info.getPersonList(i); //this method will return each person name and will be stored in items[] array
    System.out.println("The list items are:"+items[i-1]); 
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), items[i-1], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
}
```

But instead of doing for loop, and initializing the array as `private String[] items = {"Warrior","Archer","Wizard"};`, the dialog is shown up and I am not getting that error. What might be the problem here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are click the button within retrieving data from sqlite process completed. So you have to wait until the process completed. Its better to use `AsyncTask` to retrieve data from `SQLite`. For more detail refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467205/android-key-dispatching-timed-out) thread.

Comment: Hi @Gunaseelan, Thank you for the reply. I have tried AsyncTask as per your suggestion. But also I am getting the same error. Can you please provide me some sample code, if possible?