# Android app crashes - "Got RemoteException sending setActive(false)"

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-tv

I have this function that plays a file using mediaplayer

```
public boolean playURL(final String playURL, int makeBig, final int ts){
    try{
        Player.current_url = playURL;
        final String hour = Utils.getHourFromUrl(playURL);
        final String date = Utils.getDateFromUrl(playURL);
        currentPlayingDate = date;    

        int minutes = ts/60;
        String minuteToSet = Utils.appendZeros(String.valueOf(minutes));

        final String dateString = hour+":"+minuteToSet;

        currentPlayingTime = dateString;

        stateHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
        MainActivity.mediaPlayer.reset();
        MainActivity.mediaPlayer.setDataSource(playURL);
        MainActivity.mediaPlayer.prepare();
        MainActivity.mediaPlayer.seekTo(ts * 1000);

        //some more code 
}
```

It works fine, but sometimes, if I pass damaged file to it, and then press some keys, the app crashes with errors in debugger:

[image]

Note that if I just wait for it for several seconds, it won't crash and app will continue to work, it crashes only when I press some keys when mediaplayer is struggling to play damaged file.

I'm trying for hours to find solution for this and prevent the app crashing, but I can't. any help at all will be appreciated, thanks!

Edit 1: adding error logcat at the time crash happens:
http://pastebin.com/raw/taVyrvqM

Comment: i don't think the logcat warnings are relevant, try switching your logcat filter to all messages, and switch the level to error. that's way you'll see error logs from all apps and services.
also, you didn't post the crash stack-trace, please post it.

Comment: @Mister M you have to attach error logs. Now you have shared some warnings

Comment: okay added the error logcat

Comment: i think your probliem is simeilar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467205/android-key-dispatching-timed-out

Comment: Yes I saw that thread while searching, but none of the suggested solutions there helped this problem

Comment: @MisterM are you doing something with mediaPlayer (like pausing) when user click on the screen? Also, it looks like you made mediaPlayer variable static, it'll almost certainly lead to memory leak...

Comment: Not screen, the app works on android TV using remote, so when user presses a certain button corresponding action takes place, for example channel switch or increase volume.

Comment: Also, in this app I have many variables set to static, since the app is built on only one activity and classes I use are only to sort functions. It didn't occur to me memory leak could happen because of this though, could this problem be connected to that?

Comment: Are you using any service? Yes then provide detail of it.

Comment: have you tried putting your function in another thread other than the ui/main thread. it is the most likely cause of your problem.

Comment: @Yordan yes I have tried it but the result is same

Comment: @PravinDivraniya no i'm not

Comment: What happens when you use prepareAsync()? I think it will do the job for you.

Comment: already tried, but no help

Comment: Yes I knew that u tried but what am I asking is the behavior of the problem is same as in case of prepare() or there is any difference?

Comment: It's exactly the same. This behavior also happens at other random times and I'm unable to find the source of the problem